# why does it print for each time the letter appears in the word

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Why does it print 4 times for each e in the letter? Can't seem to think why it's doing this. A hint would be very helpful.

`randW` is a random 12 char words form a text file.

```
private char guess;
private String randW;
private int randNum;
private StringBuilder hiddenW = new StringBuilder("............");

void play() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Geef de letter die je wilt raden: ");
        guess = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < randW.length(); ii++) {
            if (guess == randW.charAt(ii)) {
                hiddenW.setCharAt(ii, guess);
                System.out.println(hiddenW);
                System.out.println("Aantal fouten: " + wrongG);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The random word is `GERESTOREERD`

```
This is the Output         
Geef de letter die je wilt raden: GERESTOREERD
e // user input is e 
.E..........
.E.E........
.E.E....E...
.E.E....EE..
Geef de letter die je wilt raden: GERESTOREERD
r // user input is r
.ERE....EE..
.ERE...REE..
.ERE...REER.
Geef de letter die je wilt raden: GERESTOREERD
```

Comment: What's the question exactly? What is wrong with your output? It looks ok.

Comment: i dont wont it to print 4 times like when the user  input is e. just 1 line @Tunaki

Comment: Just move `System.out.println(hiddenW);` at the end of the for loop then.

Comment: Just move the print statement out of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather that you want a single line of output for each guess. To do that, simply move the print lines outside the inner loop. If you only want to print when at least one letter was found, use a flag:

```
void play() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Geef de letter die je wilt raden: ");
        guess = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        boolean hit = false;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < randW.length(); ii++) {
            if (guess == randW.charAt(ii)) {
                hiddenW.setCharAt(ii, guess);
                hit = true;
            }
        }
        if (hit) {
            System.out.println(hiddenW);
            System.out.println("Aantal fouten: " + wrongG);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the output after the second guess, and you'll find a simple pattern:
'e' appears 4 times in the word, and the so far guessed word is printed 4 times, 'r' appears 3 times and the word is printed 3 times. And with each print another character of the word is revealed.
The reason is this piece of code:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < randW.length(); ii++) {
        if (guess == randW.charAt(ii)) {
            hiddenW.setCharAt(ii, guess);
            System.out.println(hiddenW);
            System.out.println("Aantal fouten: " + wrongG);//the printed line
        }
    }
```

Each time a character that matches the guessed char is found, the buffer is updated and the newly guessed word is printed. But once for each found character, since it's inside the same block that updates the buffer. Move the print-command out of the loop and things should work pretty fine:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < randW.length(); ii++) {
        if (guess == randW.charAt(ii)) {
            hiddenW.setCharAt(ii, guess);
        }
    }

 System.out.println(hiddenW);
 System.out.println("Aantal fouten: " + wrongG);
```